# Crossbrowser way to wrap <li> element around content?

Tags: css, width, html-lists

I'm having some problems with the dropdown menu on the page http://grantkot.com/new.
If you move your mouse over the elements which have a dropdown menu assigned, you'll see that some of the elements in the dropdown often take more than 1 line and have different widths.

What I'd like it to do is to resize all the `<li>` of the dropdown menu so that none of them goes to a new line and all the `<li>` keep the same width and steps don't appear.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.menu li li a { white-space: pre; }`

Answer (score 2):

You might give them a fixed height, otherwise they will change accordingly to their content..Either you resize the content to fit in one line, or you resize the `<li>`, which will cause those with a one-line contet to have a bigger space around them...

Comment: Won't work: I tried assigning height: 1em; to both the <li> or the <a> contained inside but that didn't help at all.

Comment: Try using a fixed height not a relative one. Or adding a display:block; as an experiment